# Question about Module "localization"

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, examples-counterexamples, localization

I'm here to ask if any of you know a counterexample for this statement:

> If $S^{-1}M=0$, then there is $s$ such that $sM=0$.

I already proved that if $M$ is finitely generated this is true. But my question is what happens in general? Once the same proof doesn't fit for the general case, I think it isn't true. However, I couldnt came up with a counterexample.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $R=\Bbb Z$ as the ring, $M=\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ as the module, and $S$ the set of non-zero elements of $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: so simple but efficient example. Thanks